# Is Aura of Liberation hampered from actually working to escape a grapple or restraint?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, grapple

The **Aura of Liberation** feature of the Oath of the Open Sea from *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says:

> Creatures that are already grappled or restrained when they enter the aura can spend 5 feet of movement to automatically escape unless they are bound by magic restraints.

The *Player's Handbook*, Appendix A, says:

> A grappled creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed. [...] A restrained creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed.

Doesn't this mean that the grappled or restrained creature has no movement to spend?

Is there some rule where you can "spend" from your normal base speed even when it is temporarily reduced? Or is this just one of those cases where we all shrug and go "eh, it is obvious what was meant"?

Comment: See also: [Is Freedom of Movement hampered from actually working to escape a grapple?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46612/is-freedom-of-movement-hampered-from-actually-working-to-escape-a-grapple), which is about a spell with similar wording.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate of the question about *freedom of movement*, since it is asking the same question about the same problematic language.

Comment: Makes sense! Hopefully this will help some people who search for the feature specifically.

Comment: Yep, that’s the main function for duplicates. It expands the space of search terms that can connect users to the answered question.